# Expected a JSON object, array, or literal

Tags: javascript, json

I've copied code from a course I'm taking and it's throwing an error. The message reads "Expected a JSON object, array, or literal" and I'm not entirely sure what I've done wrong since I'm new to using API's (fetch). Here is the screenshot from VSCode. https://www.screencast.com/t/D5oreexoCKq.

 In addition to that, this is the error that I'm getting in Chrome. https://www.screencast.com/t/Je4crxQQ4sz6

file -----> data.json

```
const json = {
    "books": [
        {
            "title": "Learn to Code",
            "author": "John Smith",
            "isbn": "324-23243"
        }, {
            "title": "The Adventures JSON",
            "author": "Jason Jones",
            "isbn": "3324-2-444"
        }, {
            "title": "New Objects",
            "author": "Jane Doe",
            "isbn": "2343-234-2433"
        }
    ]
}
```

file -----> app.js

```
JSON.books.forEach(function(val){
  console.log(val);
})
```

Comment: `const json =` isn’t JSON, so why is it in a `.json` file?

Comment: I thought that also, however, this is a screenshot from the course. https://www.screencast.com/t/g6Hpvrp4fQ, and even after removing that keyword I'm still running into this issue here https://www.screencast.com/t/Vghl2lfJpA9

Comment: A screenshot still doesn’t make it correct.. that’s simply invalid JSON (it is valid JavaScript). The second error is clearly different, and only occurs **after** the (now valid) JSON was parsed. Pay attention to each message and treat each issue separately.

Comment: @user2864740 after editing the JSON according to brk's specifications below, I am still running into this error. Does this make sense to you? https://www.screencast.com/t/Vghl2lfJpA9

Comment: Anyway, one issue at a time (and per question). SO doesn’t function well as a “live debugging” session. Try to ensure that each question is a SSCCE for the current issue.

Comment: @user2864740 could you recommend something for learning how to use API's?

Answer (score 1):

In a json file , there is no need to declare a data with `const` keyword.

your data.json should be like this

```
{
  "books": [{
    "title": "Learn to Code",
    "author": "John Smith",
    "isbn": "324-23243"
  }, {
    "title": "The Adventures JSON",
    "author": "Jason Jones",
    "isbn": "3324-2-444"
  }, {
    "title": "New Objects",
    "author": "Jane Doe",
    "isbn": "2343-234-2433"
  }]
}
```

Comment: Ok, and after removing the const keyword, I am still running into these errors with the exact same code from the course. https://www.screencast.com/t/Vghl2lfJpA9

Comment: @Nate Why is `data.json` executed as a script? JSON isn’t a script.

Comment: I agree with you. I'm just following a course on how to use API's and throwing errors based off of the code being taught.

Comment: @Nate show how you are loading the json

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I'm loading it or not with what I've written out so far. I don't have much experience working in this type of scenario.

Comment: Show us your `fetch()` command. That should get us a step further. I am also puzzled why you should store the result into a property ,(`.book`) of the predefined `JSON` object. `JSON` provides json-related methods like `.parse()` and `stringify()`.

Comment: Yeah, it's not making sense to me either. And actually, that is all the code for the project so far. I have not gotten into the fetch() method yet. We're just supposed to see that it can be displayed in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Your script in app.js needs to actually *fetch* the JSON file. Using the `JSON` object in the way you have done will not work. `JSON.books` is `undefined`.

Do something like

```
fetch("books.json").then(r=>r.json()).then(({books})=>{
  books.forEach(book=>console.log(book))
})
```

in your app.js file. This is assuming that book.json can be found in the same folder as app.js and index.html.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you. You took it a step further than where I'm at in my course and the code runs fine. It's just not the same solution as I'm being taught in my course and I'd rather understand why my code doesn't work when my instructors does when it's the same thing.